# Magento 2 : Configurable Product Page Price Change

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price, product-attribute

I imported product into magento 2. All of products are configurable products with simple products associated with them.

I am using cart2cart to achieve this. There are a bunch of issues that they seem to be able to handle well.

After a successful demo migration (took some time/customization on their behalf). I noticed that price on product pages does not update to reflect price of the simple product.

When adding product to cart, price is correctly shown (as price of simple product).

I am wondering, if this is way magento works, or if there is a setting that would change that, or if I would need to customize magento to update price on product page with either an addon or custom job.

Comment: Like this, if i select dropdown value the price change to "0", did you find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem in indexer.
Can you change all indexers to work in "on schedule" mode

Comment: I tried changing all indexers to on schedule, then I re-indexed and still the price does not change on the product page. Just to be clear is it supposed to change? can you show me a magento site with a configurable product that changes the price on the product page based on the simple product prices?